# Bash: join by numeric column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, join

If I want to use `join` on my Ubuntu, I need to first sort both files lexicographically (according to `join --help`), and only then join them:

```
tail -n +2 meta/201508_1 | sort -k 1b,1 > meta.txt
tail -n +2 keywords/copy | sort -k 1b,1 > keywords.txt
join meta.txt keywords.txt -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t'
```

(I also remove the header from both of them using `tail`)

But instead of sorting files lexicographically, I would like to sort them numerically: the first column in both files is an ID.

```
tail -n +2 meta/201508_1 | sort -k1 -n > meta.txt
tail -n +2 keywords/copy.txt | sort -k1 -n > keywords.txt
```

And then join. But for `join` these files look unsorted:

```
join: meta.txt:10: is not sorted: 1023  301000  en
join: keywords.txt:2: is not sorted: 10 keyword1
```

If I add `--nocheck-order` to `join`, it doesn't join properly - it outputs just one line.

How do I join two files on their numerical ID in bash?

Sample (columns are tab-separated):

file 1

```
id  volume lang
1   10  en
2   20  en
5   30  en
6   40  en
10  50  en
```

file 2

```
id  keyword
4   kw1
2   kw2
10  kw3
1   kw4
3   kw5
```

desired output

```
1   kw4 10  en
2   kw2 20  en
10  kw3 50  en
```

Comment: How about sorting the input files lexicographically, then joining them as in your first example, but then piping the **output** into `sort -n` to get the numeric order of keys?

Answer (score 5):

Both of these work. The first one (`sort -b` is [recommended on the Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/join.1.html))

```
join <(sed 1d file1 | sort -b) <(sed 1d file2 | sort -b) | sort -n
```

the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) recommends `sort -k 1b,1`

```
join <(sed 1d file1 | sort -k 1b,1) <(sed 1d file2 | sort -k 1b,1) | sort -n
```

In any case, you need to sort them lexicographically to join them. At the end you can still sort the result numerically.

Answer (score 1):

You can ditch `join` and use `awk` instead:

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==1{next} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{print $1, a[$1], $2, $3}' file2 file1 | column -t
1   kw4  10  en
2   kw2  20  en
10  kw3  50  en
```

It is probably already in the order that you want (as per the ID column in file1). However if you need specific sorting you can do:

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==1{next} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{
    print $1, a[$1], $2, $3}' file2 file1 | sort -nk1 | column -t
```

Note that `column -t` is there to produce tabular formatted output.

Comment: Will it work for large files? I.e. will it result in a large cross-product and filter or it'll be smarter and take advantage of the files being sorted?

Comment: No I didn't mean cache. Does it traverse both files simultaneously like `join` does, or it first creates a large cross-product between the lines of two files and then filters it?

Comment: No it doesn't create any cross-product. It traverses `file2` first and stores mapping of `$1->$2` in an associative array. Once it reaches at end of file2, it goes through `file1` and uses stored associative array data. I suggest trying it out on your larger dataset.

Comment: I didn't try, my files are too large to hold in memory.

Comment: my `file2` has only two columns. if it's 5 gb, how much ram would it occupy?

Comment: I guess it will be 8 byte per record of file2. RAMs these days are usually bigger size than this. Also is `file1` smaller in size?